# Auto-switch to wifi

Tags: linux, networking, wifi

Need to connect to specific wifi point as soon as it is in range. If it is out of range, then system must stay connected LAN. 
In case, any wifi-point is in range, there must be auto-switch.

Comment: Look like "wicd" is close to what I want. But not the perfect, and I am looking for command line options.

Answer (score 3):

Does the LAN and Wifi AP belong to the same network? If yes, then you can create a bonding device between LAN and Wifi. Bonding is done usually on servers to connect them to different network switches for redundancy and/or performance and kernel chooses which link to use. But it can be used also for your purpose (in fact, one of my colleagues uses it all the time at home - he works on Wifi, but when he want fast download speed, he just plugs in a cable and the download continues over LAN without any interruptions).

Here is a Bonding HOWTO: [bonding.txt](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt)

Comment: thanks to share about Bonding. But mine both interfaces do not share the same network.